# Cocoa: [self.view setWantsLayer:YES] brings that view above other subviews?

Tags: macos, cocoa, calayer, subview

Simply, I have an `NSView` with a bunch of subviews. In the `awakeFromNib` method (inside the view's controller), I decided to add the following:

```
[_backgroundImageView setWantsLayer:YES];
[[_backgroundImageView layer] setShadowOpacity:1.0f];
[[_backgroundImageView layer] setShadowOffset:NSMakeSize(-3, -3)];
```

The backgroundImageView is at the back of all the subviews. But, when I added the previous code, it draws the shadow correctly, but also draws the backgroundImageView above all other layers. Why? How I can Fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***You need `setWantsLayer:YES` in code for the superview.***

Turn's out I should enable the layer for the superview (self.view), too. Not only that, but I should tighten up the imageView's frame, or else it will be scaled "axis independently" even though it is set to "Proportional up or down".

Comment: Ultimately, however, I added the shadow to the image =/ .. Why? It was glitching while drawing.

Comment: Using interface builder has nothing to do with it, you just had to call setWantsLayer:YES on the _backgroundImageView's superview in code.

Comment: @valexa Right, thanks. I only discovered that when I opened the NIB file. I wish I had known that before...

Comment: Thanks for this Q&A - saved me :)